# Is there any added advantage of using djangorestframework over JsonResponse?

Tags: json, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and API creation. I am trying to figure out if it is better to use [`djangorestframework`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) or just use `JsonResponse`. I got the suggestion of `djangorestframework` from [Digital Ocean's tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react) but also found out about `JsonResponse`, which seems simpler given that I don't have to install another package.

**Goal:** I would like to be able to provide user information for both web and mobile applications.

I see that there are some reasons provided on this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/5g2dxz/when_should_i_use_djangorestframework/) for `djangorestframework`, which I pasted below for posteriority.

> The common cases for using DRF are:
>
> 1)You're creating a public-facing external API for third-party
> developers to access the data in your site, and you want to output
> JSON they can use in their apps rather than HTML.
>
> 2)You're doing mobile development and you want your mobile app to make
> GET/PUT/POST requests to a Django backend, and then have your backend
> output data (usually as JSON) to the mobile app. Since you don't want
> to pass back HTML to the mobile app, you use DRF to effectively create
> a REST API that your mobile app can call.
>
> 3)You're creating a web app, but you don't want to use the Django
> templating language. Instead you want to use the Django ORM but output
> everything as JSON and have your frontend created by a JavaScript MVC
> framework such as React, Backbone, AngularJS, etc. In those cases, you
> can use DRF to output JSON that the JavaScript framework can process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRF basically provides you many features to make APIs that you don't have in raw django.

for example:

- Serializers: a declarative way(django style like declaring models) of making serializers, when you use `JsonResponse` you have to tell everywhere what to serialize, with the serializer you have to import it and just use it, also this serializers can be able to save/update objects too. Also support ORM source to connect yours models(think how difficult would be serialize a model with nested relations with JsonResponse).
- The Web browsable API, you can see all the availables endpoints.
- Third party packages to install and use: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/third-party-packages/#existing-third-party-packages.